# Shortcut for "assign method result if method defined, otherwise default value" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

It's handy in a Ruby assignment to be able to check whether a method returns a value and, if not, provide a default:

```
my_var = foo() || my_default
```

Is there a similar shortcut to check whether the method exists in the first place? That is, a shorter version of this:

```
my_var = if defined? foo
           foo()
         else
           my_default
         end
```

Or this:

```
my_var = defined?(foo) ? foo() : my_default
```

The latter version isn't *terrible*, but when the method and variable names and default value get longer, it gets unwieldy:

```
resource_list = defined?(resource_list_override) ? resource_list_override() : [Resource.new(uri: 'http://example.org/'), Resource.new(uri: 'http://example.com/')]
```

I'd like to get it down to something that doesn't repeat the method name, if such a thing exists.

Comment: Are you using Rails or straight Ruby?  Rails has `presence`.  `my_var = foo.presence || my_default`.

Comment: Straight Ruby, alas.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a clean way to do it by default, but you can achieve something similar to `presence`.

```
class Object
  def call_default(method_name, default)
    self.respond_to?(method_name) ? self.send(method_name) : default
  end
end

my_var = call_default :foo, my_default
```

Or, if you needed to potentially send arguments to the method:

```
class Object
  def call_default(method_name, *args, default)
    self.respond_to?(method_name) ? self.send(method_name, *args) : default
  end
end

my_var = call_default :foo, 'bar', 'baz', my_default
```

Comment: But `false.presence` is `nil` so it doesn't quite work. I think the ternary is the only Ruby equivalent of CoffeeScript's `?` or Perl's `//`.

Comment: Good point, but I totally misunderstood the question anyway.  Editing now.

Comment: When I try the nil-check ternary version, I get `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: Yeah because I didn't catch the whole part about it being a method.  :-/  Sorry.  I'm updating it now.

Comment: @muistooshort - if Rails' `presence` method checked for `nil?` instead of `present?`, it would work like CS' `?`, no?  But `present?` also checks for blank strings and such.

Comment: As a Q/A writing-style thing, it isn't necessary, or particularly desirable to tack on "Edit...". We can see when you've edited something if we care. Instead of doing that simply add your new information into your text where it'd have been if you put it in originally. Stack Overflow has a goal of being like an encyclopedia or cookbook, a reference book in other words. How often do you see reference books containing "Edit..."?

Comment: @theTinMan - fair enough.  Out of all of the edits I have had, I very rarely ever add edit.  Not sure why I felt compelled to do so here.  Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `presence` is an attempt to generalize falsiness to include even more than Ruby does already but we want a narrower version. Consider `[].presence` and `{}.presence` for more examples of why it isn't The Right Thing. I think `x.nil?? y : x` is the closest Ruby to CoffeeScript's `x ? y` (but this is complicated by the presence of both `undefined` and `null` in CoffeeScript).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small method to do this...

```
def do_or_default(method, default)
  eval(method.to_s)
rescue NameError
  return default
end
```

Pass the method to be tested as a symbol.

```
def return_hello
  "hello"
end

# method return_hello exists...
p do_or_default(:return_hello, "goodbye")
=> "hello"

# method return_howdy doesn't exist...
p do_or_default(:return_howdy, "goodbye")
=> "goodbye"
```

Using `eval` is usually to be avoided but sometimes it can't be helped.  You don't want to use this if the method to be tested is supplied by your user.

Comment: `respond_to?` is a core Ruby method.  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F

Comment: oops, my bad, @SeanHill